# JavaScript: Why does getOwnPropertyDescriptor() include custom, inherited property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype, javascript-objects

I'm learning JavaScript and Node.js, and I have a question about the `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` function. Consider the following top-level code:

```
var rectangle = {
    width: 10,
    height: 5,
    get area() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }
};

Object.prototype.x = 5;

var areaPropDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(rectangle, "area");

for (var attr in areaPropDesc) {
    console.log("areaPropDesc["+attr+"] is: "+areaPropDesc[attr]);
}
```

When I execute the above code, this is the output:

```
areaPropDesc[get] is: function area() {
        return this.width * this.height;
    }
areaPropDesc[set] is: undefined
areaPropDesc[enumerable] is: true
areaPropDesc[configurable] is: true
areaPropDesc[x] is: 5
```

Why in the world is the `x` property being included in the property descriptor object of the `area` property?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `areaPropDesc` is an object which inherits from `Object.prototype`.

Since you created the `Object.prototype.x` enumerable property, when you iterate objects using `for...in` you will see that property.

To avoid that, you can

- Make `x` non-enumerable:

  ```
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'x', {
      value: 5,
      configurable: true,
      writable: true
  });
  ```
- Filter non own properties in `for...in`:

  ```
  for (var attr in areaPropDesc) if(areaPropDesc.hasOwnProperty(attr) {
      /* ... */
  }
  ```

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the property descriptor is itself an object, so it has access to the "x" on the Object prototype just like all other objects in your environment.

In other words, that "x" is not the "x" from your "rectangle" object.